# How to optimize gRPC streaming service?

Tags: c++, grpc

I use gRPC on server-side streaming

(1) server-side fetch content from remote storage, and stream it to client side one by one;

(2) client-side issue request for which file its want, and continuously receives it

Currently the bandwidth utilization is pretty poor. Observing receiving rate by `dstat -n`,

```
7773k   39k
8424k   43k
8577k   38k
9611k   51k
8209k   36k
9191k   52k
7545k   39k
7769k   36k
9082k   46k
  10M   57k
```

the average receving rate is only ~10Mpbs, and the expected rate is ~30Mbps.

When profiling the program with simply hand-written timer, I found both on client-side and server-side, >90% of time is spent on streaming.
eg: `server_stream_writer->Write(message)` and `client_stream_reader->Read(&response)`

Is there a way to know why this happens? eg: marshal/unmarshal? And how to optimize it?